# Javascript alert box for textarea values using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, textarea, alert

While submitting below:

[image: single]

It gives me an alert as "hey";

But while submitting below:

[image: multiple]

It doesn't alert anything.

PHP Code:

```
$text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['tval']);
echo "<script>alert('".$text."');</script>";
```

HTML Code:

```
<textarea cols="40" rows="5" type="text" name="tval" placeholder="Type Here..." required></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a line break in your javascript code, so it produces an error. You can check the Developer Console (F12) to see what the error is. This however, should fix the problem:

```
$text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['tval']);
echo "<script>alert('". json_encode($text) ."');</script>";
```

json_encode is a quick and easy way to transform line breaks in a string into the \n format, which the alertbox supports. See here:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_alert2

**Update:** [See demo here](https://3v4l.org/ObCYA)

**Update 2:** Make sure to only run this code snippet if your form is submitted, and the 'tval' is set in POST, otherwise you'll get a warning, and PHP will interpret the empty value as null. Example:

```
if(isset($_POST['tval'])) {
    $text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['tval']);
    echo "<script>alert('". json_encode($text) ."');</script>";
}
```

Comment: it gives alert with null displayed, also some php warnings on the page

Comment: I updated my answer with what I believe to be the issue. If I'm incorrect, please post what kind of warnings you receive.

Comment: There was a typo while placing the code, it works. How can we get different alerts for each new line?

Comment: Then you need to forget about the json_encode thing, and just explode the input into separate lines, and alert them as they are. See example here: https://3v4l.org/hkefn

Answer (score 0):

You can use template literals to write strings with new lines:

```
$text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['tval']);
echo "<script>alert(`".$text."`);</script>";
```

from your comments:

You can use `split()` and `map()` to get different alert for different lines:

```js
//var text = `<?php echo $text;?>`
var text = `firstline
secondline
thirdline`; //example text for snippet
text.split("\n").map((line)=>{
  alert(line);
});
```

Comment: it gives an alert but no text displayed in it

Comment: There was a typo while placing the code, it works. How can we get different alerts for each new line?

Comment: @fayix74171 I updated my answer. See snippet to learn something new.